# Как отключить автовоспроизведение видео?

Tags: html, видео

```
<object width="470" height="353">
  <param name="movie" value="{$row.track}">
  <param name="wmode" value="window">
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
  <embed  src="{$row.track}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="window" allowfullscreen="true" width="470" height="353">
</object>
```

Comment: autoplay='false' так пробовали ?

Comment: а куда вставлять?

Comment: делал так <param name="autoplay" value="false">

Comment: в object возле width и height , не факт что поможет

Comment: тоже ставил и не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так :

```
 <param name="play" value="false">
```