# iframe выключить autoplay

Tags: html, iframe

```
<iframe  width = "258" height = "258" autoplay="false" autoplay="0" src = "{$row.track}?autoplay=0">
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/796411/186083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `autoplay="0"` заменить на `autoplay= false` В случае с youtube не много [подругому](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) Или просто уберите атрибут `autoplay`

Comment: пробовал, не срабатывало, поставил обычный video и начало работать